# How do spambots find and submit to email opt-in the end of a funnel?

Tags: web-crawlers, spam, forms, spam-prevention, spam-bots

I have an opt-in page that's being nuked right now with spambots. A simple webpage that I use to allow subscribers into my email list.

The only way to get to that page was through one of my tracking links

So my "tracking link" basically contains a "funnel" within it. 
tracking link = (opt in page 1 --> landing page --> etc)

So If I change the Url on my opt in page, the tracking link will still get to it because the page is simply updated

So quick question:

**How are spambots sent to the form they're spamming?**

- Do they save the link of the opt in page?
- Do they "download the form"    and simply send to it from there? ..
  or what? (a nasty idea by the way)

Because I've tried disconnecting that initial opt in page out of the funnel. Out of the tracking link.. meaning if you hit the tracking link you no longer go to that opt in page.

And I've also tried changing the Url in my site directory.

Yet I'm still seeing signups.

**Do spambots have the form itself saved & just send directly to it?**

And I'm afraid to just "delete that opt in page" because my tracking link has other opt in pages attached that it rotates to. 
And I don't want to leave those links out there so it can affect my main list.

I got real lucky that they picked the email list & opt in page I was going to delete anyway :D

Comment: I'm afraid it's hard to answer the question for a specific case. Spambots only need to know the URL where they have to send the data, and the data format to send. Generally the URL of the html form is not relevant. Mostly it depends on the data collection script.

Comment: Thanks that's what I was thinking.
because I've literally been changing the URL. I've been changing all of the links.. not to mention, it's not hitting my tracking link which should rotate the link. 
So I'll just change the "form confirmation page" to FBI.gov and forget about it & keep trimming that list.